# How can I import a DMA-BUF file descriptor into an OpenCV cv::Mat?

Tags: linux, opencv

I am working with an API (libcamera) that gives me back DMA-BUF file descriptors containing raw image data. Is there any way of importing a DMA-BUF file descriptor into an OpenCV `cv::Mat`? I get the file descriptor from the [FrameBuffer instance's plane method](https://libcamera.org/api-html/structlibcamera_1_1FrameBuffer_1_1Plane.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to mmap the buffer data into a pointer and then create an OpenCV Mat from it. You can do it like so

```
uint8_t *ptr = static_cast<uint8_t *>(mmap(NULL, buffer->planes()[0].length, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0));
cv::Mat image(height, width, CV_8UC1, ptr, stride);
```

where buffer is part of the libcamera::FrameBuffer class. You would have used buffer to create the fd in the first place, using something along the lines of

```
int fd = buffer->planes()[0].fd.get();
```